# Database of 3D crystal models

Tags: crystal-structure

I'm looking for a database of very basic crystal models for all the various types - triclinic, monoclinic, orthorhombic, tetragonal, rhombohedral, hexagonal, and cubic.

A basic example would be a CAD file for a cube, to represent the cubic structure. I don't want like a packing model which shows the individual atoms because I'm trying to represent macroscopic crystals.

Any ideas where I could find what I'm looking for? Not a 3D graphic designer.

Comment: [Crystallographic database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_database). CAD file formats are not used in crystallography (maybe unless you are an architect building another [Atomium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomium)), look for CIF instead.

Comment: There are exactly seven of them, all of which you already listed in your question. Why a *database*? And what do you want to do with them, with what software?

Comment: sounds like you need a database of polyhedra, not chemicals

Comment: for example, something like : https://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/vp.html

Answer (score 3):

Joining `@Karl`'s comment on «what do you want to do with them?» the work *to present* point groups is work already solved.  For off-line teaching, the freely accessible collection of the [32 point groups](https://www.uab.cat/web/la-divulgacio/grups-puntuals-de-simetria-1345664584325.html) by Casas and Estop by (UB Barcelona) may suit your needs:

[image]

The model data are provided as interactive 3D `.pdf` files which a reader like Adobe Acrobat 9.0 may let you toggle on/off the axes / planes, etc.

Beside some background provided [here](https://www.uab.cat/web?cid=1096481466574&pagename=UABDivulga%2FPage%2FTemplatePageDetallArticleInvestigar&param1=1345668620213), the authors outline the workflow and tools used (SolidWorks, Adobe Illustrator CS3, and Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro) in an accompanying publication ([doi 10.1016/j.cageo.2013.09.004](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cageo.2013.09.004), paywall).  Later, the concept was extended to cover the space groups as to complement the International Tables of Crystallography, too ([title page](https://it.iucr.org/resources/symmetrydatabase/), paywall).